# Name for mode of work where you type commands and they are executed right away

Tags: language-agnostic

How is the style of the [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html#X7FE7C0C17E1ED118) system and Python programming called? The Scale may be written in this style as well.

I mean the style when you write a line by line and execute it instantaneously.

Comment: Interactively via a REPL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an interactive console, a REPL (read-eval-print loop), or a (language) shell.